# Display organization keeps changing back to its initial configuration

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64. The display organization keeps changing back to its initial configuration when I try changing it. What could cause the issue?

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.